# Restar stock de productos al realizar una Venta

Tags: c#, mysql, base-de-datos, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio en *Windows Forms* y *MySQL* como gestor de base de datos.

¿Cómo resto en inventarios cuando realice una Venta?

Ese es el código que ocupo para el botón guardar venta. Los datos, se agregan a una tabla venta, y los campos de las tablas. El código funciona y me guarda, pero quiero restar del inventario.

Código del botón guardar:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Login.Venta_Tienda.VentaR pCliente = new Login.Venta_Tienda.VentaR();

     pCliente.Idproducto_V = textBox1.Text.Trim();
     pCliente.Producto_V = comboBox1.Text.Trim();
     pCliente.Cantidad_V = textBox2.Text.Trim(); 

     pCliente.Preciocxu_V = textBox3.Text.Trim(); 

     pCliente.Total_V = textBox5.Text.Trim();

     pCliente.Fechafac_V = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year
       + "/" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Month + "/" + dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;

     int resultado = Login.Venta_Tienda.MetodosVenta.Agregarp(pCliente);
     if (resultado > 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(
           "Venta Guardado Con Exito!!", "Guardado", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
           MessageBoxIcon.Information
         );
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show(
           "No se pudo guardar el cliente", "Fallo!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
           MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
         );
     }
}
```

Campos de la tabla `ventatienda`:

```
Idventa Int,
Idproducto VARCHAR,
Producto VARCHAR,
Cantidad  VARCHAR,
Preciocxu  VARCHAR,
Total  VARCHAR,
Fechafac  VARCHAR
```

Campos de la tabla `inventariomarket`:

```
campos  INT,
IdProducto  VARCHAR,
Producto  VARCHAR,
Existencias  VARCHAR,
Precioxunidad  VARCHAR,
Proveedor  VARCHAR,
Fecha_Recibido  Date
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te recomiendo editar tu pregunta y concretar los detalles. Ponte en el lugar de alguien que no tiene ni idea de cómo es la tabla a la que quieres acceder ni la arquitectura de tu código... tu pregunta tal cual está descrita no aporta información suficiente.

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, acabo de poner el codigo que ocupo para el boton guardar

Comment: Vale, ahora intenta que las imágenes no sean imprescindibles para entender la pregunta. Piensa que en el futuro los links pueden no estar disponibles y entonces tu pregunta no será de utilidad para nadie. Las imágenes tienen que ser algo complementario. Además, si pones el código directamente en vez de una captura facilitas que la gente lo pueda copiar para hacer pruebas y darte una respuesta más acertada. El poder copiar el código también facilita la tarea de escribir la respuesta ya que no es necesario reescribir tu código.

Comment: @sunohara en la pregunta que haces no entiendo muy bien tu dices: como resto a una tabla de datos en MySql , desde un formulario de compras en C#, la cantidad a llevar de un producto??? Cuando el negocio hace una Compra tu Stock aumenta entonces tienes que sumar la existencia y si el negocio hace una Venta es lo contrario, puedes entrar al chat para poder explicarte mejor.

Comment: ok, quitare las imagenes y pondre el codigo, lo siento si os hecho enfadar

Comment: @sunohara http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @PedroÁvila no puedo responder en el chat, soy nuevo y no me deja, solo lectura, aun asi gracias bro!

Comment: Ok, he editado tu pregunta esperemos si la reabren para que te podamos apoyar.

Comment: ok! Gracias por la ayuda @PedroÁvila

Comment: @sunohara Elabora mejor tus preguntas, tomate tu tiempo antes de publicarla ya que existe un standar de calidad de pregunta, para si los usuarios de este foro puedan aportar a tus preguntas y así obtines respuestas mas rápidas, suerte!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, deberías tener un modelo relacional parecido a este, el cual no pretendo que sea una solución, pero sí un alcance al diseño de tu base de datos.

[image: Inventario]

Cuando realizas el proceso de la Venta, debe impactar en tu tabla de Inventarios restando el stock de producto. Para eso debes hacer al momento de registrar la venta.

```
UPDATE inventariomarket
    SET stock = stock - @cantidad 
    WHERE IdAlmacen = @IdAlmacen AND IdProducto = @IdProducto
```

También podrías crear un *Store Prodecure* y hacer algo como esto:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xspAfectaDetalleBodegaArticulo] 
(
    @idBodega VARCHAR(2),
    @idArticulo VARCHAR(6),
    @idMovimiento INT,
    @cantidad INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO DetalleBodegaArticulo(idBodega, idArticulo, idMovimiento, cantidad)
    VALUES(@idBodega, @idArticulo, @idMovimiento, @cantidad)

    IF  @IdMovimiento = 2 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS( SELECT idBodega FROM BodegaArticulos WHERE idBodega = @idBodega AND idArticulo = @idArticulo ) 
            UPDATE BodegaArticulos
            SET stock = stock + @cantidad 
            WHERE idBodega = @idBodega AND idArticulo = @idArticulo
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO BodegaArticulos
            VALUES ( @idBodega, @idArticulo , @cantidad)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS( SELECT idBodega FROM BodegaArticulos WHERE idBodega = @idBodega AND idArticulo = @idArticulo ) 
            UPDATE BodegaArticulos
            SET stock = stock - @cantidad 
            WHERE idBodega = @idBodega AND idArticulo = @idArticulo
        ELSE
            PRINT('NO PUEDES REALIZAR LA VENTA, DEBIDO A QUE NO HAY PRODUCTOS EN STOCK')
    END
END
```

Tienes que adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: gracias amigo! vere como lo adapto, gracias @PedroÁvila .

Comment: @sunohara No te olvides de votar como util si la respuesta te ayudo en algo o marcar como respuesta si soluciono tu problema.

Comment: @PredroÁvila creo que ya lo hice, me avisas

Answer (score 0):

Debes rescatar el dato desde la tabla posterior a eso restarle la cantidad que lleva el cliente y el nuevo dato volver a escribirlo en la base de datos. Como no dejas código no puedo ayudarte en ver si tienes un error en especifico o algo.

Te dejo algunos enlaces de como realizar la conexión Mysql y C#:

Enlace 1: http://evilnapsis.com/2015/07/10/conectar-visual-studio-y-csharp-con-mysql/

Enlace 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8R3-EXqQIM

Comment: Una respuesta basada únicamente en enlaces no es considerada válida porque dichos enlaces pueden dejar de ser accesibles en el futuro. Llegado ese momento tu respuesta será completametne estéril. Los enlaces están bien para complementar la respuesta pero **nunca** deben ser imprescindibles.

Comment: gracias, muy buen aporte! , y si mis conecciones son como las del video, lo unico que me falta es restar de un formulario de compras, la cantidad en existencias menos la cantidad a llevar, para tener el nuevo dato de existencias en el formulario de inventario, y no encuentro como hacer esa relacion en codigo, ya intente un par de formas y no me sale.

Comment: @eferion Me inicio hace poco en Stackoverflow y no he leido por completo las reglas. Tu recomendacion seria eliminar la respuesta o modificarla, gracias por la aclaracion.

Comment: @sunohara deberias dejar un poco de codigo para ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: @sunohara lo recomendable es editar la pregunta para respetar el historial de la misma. Podrías empezar por indicar la estructura de la tabla a modificar así como el elemento de la misma que deseas cambiar. También sería necesario saber qué mecanismo utilizas para comunicarte con la base de datos... cosas así